Why can't I import HiddenMarkovModel from pomegranate packet?
When I do this:
from pomegranate import HiddenMarkovModel
It will run with this problem: ImportError: cannot import name 'HiddenMarkovModel' from 'pomegranate'.
What's wrong with it? My pomegranate version is 1.0.4.
I want to find a way to do it. I see others can use this code to import correctly.
